# Does Quickblox javascript sdk works in nativescript?

Tags: quickblox, nativescript, quickblox-android

I understand that Quickblox javascript sdk uses jquery and nodejs modules. So does it work with nativescript?

Comment: its better to ask this in quickblox forum (or nativescript forum) for better results

Comment: @NikosM. Quickblox support page suggested to raise a question in this.

Comment: please provide reason when you down vote a question.

Answer (score 1):

In NativeScript you can use node modules, which don't have platform dependecies.

Quickblox JavaScript sdk depends on jQuery, which uses the DOM. This means that it is not possible to use it. However Quickblox also has also iOS and Android sdk, which you can use. To do that you will have to wrap them in plugins. More information about it could be found in [the {N} documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now QuickBlox supports NativeScript (QuickBlox on-boarding advisor here).

Quoting [from our blog post](https://quickblox.com/blog/nativescript-sdk-support-is-ready-for-apps/):

> Start your integration today – go to QuickBlox Javascript main hub and connect JS SDK 2.8 and above. With this update you do not need to change anything in your code – the same Javascript API is supported under NativeScript, Browser and Node.js

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk/releases/tag/2.8.0

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own product, website or blog, **you must disclose your affiliation in the answer**. Otherwise, your answer may be flagged as spam. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).